# Redshift Data API Output tabular formatting

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to format the output of the get-statement-result into the tabular format in Redshift Data API?

I am executing sql statements & fetching results using below statement:

Statement 1:

```
aws redshift-data execute-statement --region us-east-2 --cluster-identifier test --database dev --db-user admin --profile test  --sql "select * from stl_query limit 1"
```

Statement 2:

```
aws redshift-data get-statement-result --profile test --region us-east-2 --id "id frm statement 1"
```